# How to calculate sum of ASCII?

Tags: java

I want to calculate the sum of each variable and string from "E" to the last "dash" variable, currently it only calculates the "message" variable:

```
physicalLayer.sendFrame(open + "E" + dash + length + dash + message + dash + total + close);
```

here is my full code :

```
String open = "<";
String close = ">";
String dash = "-";
int length = message.length();
int total = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < message.length(); i++)
    {
        int mod = message.charAt(i);
        total += mod;
    }

physicalLayer.sendFrame(open + "E" + dash + length + dash + message + dash + total + close);
```

For example

input message is :

```
hello
```

output message :

```
<E-05-hello-532>
```

Comment: What do you want it to do instead? BTW, `String.format("<E-%d-%s-%d>", length, message, total)` is much easier to read.

Comment: I want to calculate the values of "E, -, 05, -, h, e, l, l, o" as the ASCII of "hello" is 532, it should output 837

Comment: And does `message` contain `E-05-hello` already? (If not, how do you plan to include "E-05-" in the sum?)

Comment: no the message is 'hello', this 'E-05-hello-' is a frame. I want to calculate the whole frame.

Comment: So, you are complaining that your code calculates the wrong value when you apply it to the wrong data...? Please put in a bit of effort, pal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String message = "hello java";
String open = "<";
String close = ">";
String dash = "-";
int length = message.length();
int total = 0;

String str = "E-" + (length < 10 ? "0" : "") + length + "-" + message + "-";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    int mod = str.charAt(i);
    total += mod;
}
String output = open + str + total + close;
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: nice try! but It doesn't work when the length of the message changes. For instance I tried : <E-6-helloo-948> 948 is wrong correct ans is 949 .

Comment: That's what I said 
here the constant is changed from E-05-message- to E-6-helloo-

Comment: I am not going to tell you the code for that. Work around and show the code

Comment: yes I know I have to change the constant every time I input a certain msg. However, this not what I was looking for, cheers for trying anyways.

Comment: tell me, i assume that the output for "hello java" will be <E-10-hello java-1283>.
Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct when you ignore the constant idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94629/discussion-between-dwear-and-shivam7357).